# IQKeyboardManager for iOS 11 Xcode 9.2 Cannot build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm trying to integrate IQKeyboardManager in my application. Due to few existing constrains I can only drag and drop the library into my project. However when I try to compile the project I get the following errors.
[image]

I'm using Objective-C and targeting iOS 11.0.

Please help me know what I'm missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: don't post screenshot, just embed your code, please.

Comment: Sorry about that, However these errors are coming from the IQKeyboardManager classes only. I'm just trying to find out if there is any setting I missed which is causing all these errors only in IQKeyboardManager.

Comment: why u try pod file?

pod 'IQKeyboardManager' #iOS8 and later

pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '3.3.7' #iOS7

Comment: What is your deployment target number and xcode version no?

Comment: Deployment Target:11.0 and Xcode:9.2

Comment: your IQKeyboardManager version is above 3.3.7 ?

Comment: I have just download the latest from github. So it must be upto date.

Comment: Ok No problem ..just try this code  .please change from __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
 to          __weak typeof(self) IQKeyboardManager = self;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167689/discussion-between-prateek-raj-and-unknown-devloper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried "`__weak IQKeyboardManager *weakSelf = self;`" and "`__strong IQKeyboardManager *strongSelf = weakSelf;`"

instead of "`__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`" and "`__strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;`"

This cleared my issue.

Can anyone please suggest why this was happening.